# What are some benefits of having a single child folder?

Tags: gui-design, workflow, mac-os-x

Let me rephrase the question:

> What are some benefits of having a single actionable event on screen (e.g. single child folder, single button occupying the whole
>   screen estate, etc.), **immediately followed by the user-induced activity** (e.g.
>   double clicking on a folder on Finder to see its contents, clicking on
>   an actionable button in an application, etc.)?

To illustrate the question, I've taken an example from the file structure *every* OSX application seems to have:

[image: Screenshot showing the option "Show Package Contents"]

> Step #1: We're going to click on "Show Package Contents" to see the contents of "App Store.app".

[image: Screenshot showing only content, "Contents" folder.]

> Step #2: After the click, we realize there's only one folder, "Contents". This seems redundant, because the users most likely had decided to see the contents of "App Store.app" in Step #1 already.

[image: Screenshot showing .app's contents of "Contents" folder.]

> Step #3: Here are the real "Contents" of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense in theory, but can be highly justified in practice.

## The Apple bundle case

One example of practical justification is provided [by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/cfbundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html):

> While the Contents directory might seem superfluous, it identifies the bundle as a modern-style bundle and separates it from document and legacy bundle types found in earlier versions of Mac OS.

Now let's delve into more details.

## The theory

You have raised an extremely important point when it comes to structuring, where this rule is next to unchallenged:

> If a parent has only got one child, either replace the parent with the child, or remove the child.

Examples include:

- Don't have a menu item that only has one sub-menu item.
- Don't have a chapter in a book that only has one sub-heading.

Reason being, that a parent (or *container*) is created as a **grouping** entity for other elements - but a group must have more than one member, or it cannot be called a *group*.

To illustrate, this menu hierarchy:

- Products

  - Cars
  - Motorcycles
  - Bikes
- Services

  - Repairs
  - Trading
  - Sales
- **Get in touch**

  - **Contact us**

Should really be:

- Products

  - Cars
  - Motorcycles
  - Bikes
- Services

  - Repairs
  - Trading
  - Sales
- **Contact us**

## The practice

### Classification consistency

It is often important (IA comes to mind here) that all items on a particular level has the same classification.

Consider the following:

- Cars

  - Fiat
  - Skoda
  - Ford
- **Bikes**

  - **Peugeot**

The first alternative is confusing:

- Cars

  - Fiat
  - Skoda
  - Ford
- **Peugeot**

the second is little ideal:

- Cars

  - Fiat
  - Skoda
  - Ford
- **Peugeot bikes**

### Future usage

Whether a shopping list, or a folder hierarchy, it is well possible that initially a container will only have one item. Like in this case:

- Development

  - Desktop
  - Mobile
  - Web

    - My first site

The `Web` folder may have one sub-folder, but it's all logical and some folders *may* be introduced in the future.